# How to edit a simple header on the title page only?

Tags: header-footer

I am writing my thesis and I don't want to use any other headers except on the cover page, which is basically a title page. I use the scrreprt class. If I use the following code, I can clearly see that there is a section for headers, therefore I shouldn't have to create it, but only edit it somehow.

```
\documentclass[final,twoside,BCOR=0.7cm,DIV=calc,openright]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \begin{titlepage}
        I want this part in the header

        This in the body of the title page
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

I would rather not use the fancyhdr for two reasons:

1. I feel like this is a very simple task and it shouldn't require a package. The header is already there and it has a 0 length text. I don't want to style the header in any way, so it feels like an overkill to use any package, nonetheless one which is named fancy
2. I tried to use fancyhdr and I managed to add a header, but I had to use the \thispagestyle{fancy}, which adds page numbering on the titlepage. I imagine that there are solutions to remove the page number, but this would mean to fix a problem which I didn't have from the beginning.

The first googol pages on google about headers and latex are about how much fancy stuff you can do if you use fancyhdr. What if I don't want to be fancy, any solutions?

Comment: You can use a negative value for vspace (`\vspace*{-2cm}`) to move the text a bit up. It is a titlepage, which needs special care. `showframe` shows you the margins (and head) of normal pages. [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993)

Comment: Thank you, I think that the `\vspace*{-2cm}` is what I'll use, but this feels more like a hack. Maybe there is an actual way to edit the actual heading. About showframe... you mean that the title page might not actually have a head section and showframe only prints the margins of the normal style?

Comment: It is a titlepage, often they have a different set of margins than the rest of the document. Titlepages need special care and manually adjusting and placing stuff is normal. *There are no hacks on title pages.* ;-)

Comment: btw, if you are interested: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[final,twoside,BCOR=0.7cm,DIV=calc,openright]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \thispagestyle{headings}
        \markboth{I want this part in the header}{I want this part in the header}
        \def\thepage{}
        I want this part in the header

        This in the body of the title page
    \end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This adds numbering to the page, because it changes the style of the page, so it has the same problem as fancyhdr. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: this seems to work, thank you, but could you elaborate a bit what \def\thepage{} does actually do?

Comment: It defines the _output_ of the pagenumber to nothing, but only local to the titlepage

Comment: while it is a solution that works, it is not what I expected. One of the reason's why I didn't want to use fancyhdr, as I explained in the question, is that it would add page numbering and then I would have to fix this problem, that I didn't have at the beginning. For now I will wait some more, to see if anyone has a solution that does exactly what I asked, meaning, editing the head section of the page, without modifying anything else. I understand that one of the reasons such a solution is hard to find is because it doesn't exist, but for now, let's see if other people have any more ideas

Comment: @Andrei You are setting a titlepage. Titlepages are set `empty` that means the header and footer are completely empty. Once you change it to not empty, you need to revert the parts that got changed as well (pagenumber).

Comment: @Johannes_B After your explanation, I got it that this answer is the closest possible answer to my question(no package, simple header), so I'll mark it as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a header to be only on the cover page, then it is not a header at all. You could just include a text with altered font at the top of the page with desired alignment (XeLaTeX makes this a little easier for me).

Comment: Thank you, you are right, but because I was using showframe, I thought that the title environment has a reserved header space and I thought that I am supposed to use it, since it's there. Now I know better from @Johannes_B comment that showframe shows the frame for normal pages, even on the title page and the title page doesn't really have a any kind of header section in it, so I can simply just write some text and get it out of the text section by using a negative `\vspace{-2cm}`

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer of @Herbert solves your problem in a simple and good way.

If want a command that sets only a header on the current page you could load package `scrlayer` which is part of the KOMA-Script bundle and define a layer page style. But IMHO this is some kind of overkill to your problem.

```
\documentclass[final,twoside,BCOR=0.7cm,DIV=calc,openright]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer{header}
\newcommand*\thispageonlythisheader[1]{%
  \DeclareLayer[background,head,contents={#1}]{header}%
  \DeclarePageStyleByLayers{header}{header}%
  \thispagestyle{header}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\begin{titlepage}
  \thispageonlythisheader{\hfill I want this part in the header}
  \blindtext
\end{titlepage}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\Blindtext
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\thispageonlythisheader{\hfill Here is also text in the header but nothing in the footer}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: After a little bit more research about how things works in latex in general, I agree that @Herbert's answer matches my question as close as possible, so I'll have to mark that as an answer, but your answer is also interesting.